# Beeping noise every 3 seconds

Tags: electrical, noise

Its in the middle of the night and I’ve been woken by a random beeping noise that beeps every 3 seconds. I cannot find where the exact noise is coming from. I even shut of the breaker one by one but it is still beeping. Any idea where this could be coming from? I added a link to a video where you can hear the beeps.

Link to video: https://imgur.com/a/COIyzMv

Comment: Do you have smoke alarms? This sort of thing comes up every so often. While the exact sound changes, the method for tracking it down is similar

Comment: It's hard to tell from the recording but that doesn't sound like a simple piezo buzzer. I would first look for something that can produce a range of sounds, and, if you turned the breakers off for at least a minute, something battery powered. My answer to the question I linked discusses how to locate a mystery sound.

Comment: Does someone you know have a warped sense of humor? https://www.thegreenhead.com/2008/12/annoy-a-tron-2.php

Comment: I'd also second checking the smoke alarms, but they usually start chirping on a much longer time scale (minutes, not seconds). What other battery-powered things do you have in your house? Do you have a burglar alarm system with battery backup that has come unplugged from its normal ac outlet?